# PHP - Executing PHP from a string

Tags: php

This one is a bit of a weird one. Ive created a function designed to select a template and either include it or parse the %0, %1,%3 etc. variables. This is the current function:

```
if(!fopen($tf,"r")){
    $this->template("error",array("404"));
}
$th = fopen($tf,"r");
$t = fread($th, filesize($tf) );
$i=0;
for($i;$i<count($params);$i++){
    $i2 = '%' . $i;
    $t = str_replace($i2,$params[$i],$t);
}
echo $t . "\n";
fclose($th);
```

Where $th is the relative directory to my template file. My issue is, I need to execute the PHP inside of these files whilst at the same tme being able to replace the string variables %0 %1 etc.
How could I go about attempting this?

Comment: If you cannot find another solution then `eval()` will execute your PHP code within your template. This is a final solution! Even then, you are kinda in trouble if you use it. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Why not use one of the ready made template engines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in my comment I think a template engine like Smarty would probably serve you better but here's how I'd do it with output buffering rather than `eval()`

Something like this

```
ob_start();
include "your_template_file.php";
$contents = ob_get_contents();  // will contain the output of the PHP in the file
ob_end_clean();

// process your str_replace() variables out of $contents
```

Comment: Thank you :)
And the reason I don't want to use smarty is because i'd like to create my own simple template parser for use in future projects